# Как мне сделать чат на питоне где пользователь сам выбирает с каким пользователем общаться?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, kivy, socket.io

У меня вопрос как можно сделать чат на питоне где пользователь может выбрать с каким пользователем общаться как по типу ватсап или телеграмм?

И если можно то как мне это еще и на глобальную сеть вывести чтобы другие могли пользоваться?

Comment: Сделать можно, но долго)
Используйте библиотеку socket
Для реализации выбора пользователя, с которым пользователь хочет общаться, можно добавить дополнительную логику, например, создавать отдельные потоки для каждого подключения и хранить информацию о том, с какими пользователями уже установлено соединение.
тЧобы сделать приложение доступным всем, можно разместить его на сервере - Amazon Web Services, Google Cloud Platform, Microsoft Azure и другие. Также понадобится зарегистрировать доменное имя и настроить DNS-записи для связи вашего домена с IP-адресом вашего веб-сервера.

Comment: Возьму идею локалки. Думаю перевести это в глобальную сеть будет не сложнее. Пиши API, ваша программа будет к нему обращаться. API взаимодействует с базой данной и хранит диалоги/сообщения/etc. В случае, если что-то на сервере с юзером изменилось, уведомляешь его об этом. В-принципе так можно сделать свой месседжер